# SVN Monitor like software for Git repositories

Tags: svn, git

Is there anything like [SVN Monitor](http://www.svnmonitor.com/) for Git repositories? Something that will enable me to monitor checkins and do comparisons.

Answer (score 5):

I recently wrote [scm-notifier](https://github.com/pocorall/scm-notifier) that can monitor both Git and SVN repositories. It is a port of well known [SVN notifier](http://svnnotifier.tigris.org/), which means that scm-notifier also supports fancy GUI.

Comment: I've added .net 4.5 support here https://github.com/regisbsb/scm-notifier Thanks @pocorall!

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich -- everything works fine. tested today. Git 2.9.0 [x64]

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything like SVN Monitor for Git repositories?

Nothing as fancy and icon-colored than that, no.

I think SVN Monitor is a DVCS answer to a *central* VCS tool problem: how do I monitor potential parallel evolutions and conflicts to multiple "projects" (read "distant repositories")

But all of those problems are built right in Git: just add a remote repo, fetch it and you have in your local repo so much more than just "svn log".

You can then make all the diff and rebase and merge you want between branches coming from various distant repo (because they have been fetched)

You can also configure those same remote repo to not accept non fast-forward merge, forcing you to solve any conflict first locally, before pushing them to your other "projects".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SVNMonitor, however Git does have a set of [hooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) that get executed on various different events in the repository. For instance, [`post-receive`](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive) is executed on the remote repository after each `git push`.

The hooks are just scripts that live in the hooks directory of your repository and are initially disabled by the presence of a .sample suffix on the file name.

So, if you're happy to do some scripting, you could edit the appropriate hook(s) for the repository event(s) that you are interested in, and perform whatever specific operations you wish to replicate from SVNMonitor.

Comment: Question is about a software where you can monitor a repository, like SVN Monitor

Answer (score 0):

[Git Notifier](http://github.com/marcocampana/git-notifier#readme) looks like it would provide some of the functionality of SVN Monitor... except the front-end uses the OS X framework Growl for notifications. I'm guessing you're wanting a Windows solution?

Depending on how the underlaying code is structured you may be able to rip out the Growl stuff and replace with (another notification technology).